# Dividing numbers between two different arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays, list, methods, division

This is my first post.  Thank you in advance for your understanding and help on this topic.  I am trying to divide two numbers between two different arrays. My data is being pulled from a .txt file.  I'm given the name, gallons, and miles.  I'm trying to calculate MPG. So I would have to divide gallons[0] by miles[0], gallons[1] by miles[1],etc.... and display this in the list in the cmd window. Below is the code that I have so far.  Please note that the pseudo'd out method at the bottom was what I was trying before I tried the method above it. I apologize in advance if this has been addressed/answered in a previous thread.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
public class mpgHOmework2{
    public static void main(String[]args) throws IOException{

    File fn = new File("mpg.txt");
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(fn);

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    String[] names = new String[10];
    int[] miles = new int[10];
    int[] gallons = new int[10];
    double mpg;

    fillArray(inputFile,names,miles,gallons);

    displayArray(names,miles,gallons,mpg(miles,gallons));

    }//end main method
//==================================================================
    public static void fillArray(Scanner input,String[] arrIn, int[] arr1In, int[] arr2In){

        for(int indx = 0; indx < arrIn.length; indx++){
            arrIn[indx] = input.nextLine();
            if(arrIn[indx].length() == 0)arrIn[indx] = input.nextLine();
            arr1In[indx] = input.nextInt();
            arr2In[indx] = input.nextInt();}


    }//end fillArray method
//==================================================================
    public static void displayArray(String[] arrIn,int[] arr1In, int[]arr2In, double mpg){

        System.out.printf("%-18s   %5s    %7s   %3s\n","Names","Miles","Gallons","MPG");
        System.out.printf("%-18s   %5s    %7s   %3s\n","==================","=====","=======","===");
        for(int indx = 0; indx < arrIn.length; indx++)
            System.out.printf("%-18s   %5d   %7d  %.2f\n",arrIn[indx],arr1In[indx],arr2In[indx],mpg);

    }//end displayArray method
//==================================================================
    public static double mpg(Scanner input,String[] arrIn, int[] arr1In, int[] arr2In){

        for(int indx = 0; indx < arrIn.length; indx++){
            arrIn[indx] = input.nextLine();
            if(arrIn[indx].length() == 0)arrIn[indx] = input.nextLine();
            arr1In[indx] = input.nextInt();
            arr2In[indx] = input.nextInt();
        return = arr1In[indx]/arr2In[indx];}
}enter code here
/*  public static double mpg(int[] arrOneIn, int[] arrTwoIn){

        double retValue = 0.0;
            int a = 0;
            int b = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < arrOneIn.length-1; i++){
                return [i] = arrOneIn[i] / arrTwoIn[i];
                }

            return a/b;
    }//end mpg method*/
}//end class
```

This is the mpg.txt file.  Sorry I just signed up 10 min ago and don't know how to navigate the site yet.

```
John Murphy
1200  60
Katherine Cleary
1500 63
Isaac Fajerman
2600 87
Marsha Smiith
3500 100
Jason Meier
4100 196
Inna Johnson
750 34
Walter Philips
6900 265
Tracey Cannon
5024 187
Sheryl Rothman
6800 323
Jeff Gottlieb
450 18
```

Thanks for your time.

-Rob

Comment: Are you required to read the data in using arrays?  In other words, why not just do the computation as you read in the values?  And welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Yes. I'm currently taking a Java class and the professor is going over arrays.  How can I do the computation to read in the values? A classmate and I have been trying to figure this out for days.   Thank you!

Comment: You should also edit your question and explain exactly what problem(s) you are having. It isn't clear from your question.

Comment: Your loops and return statement isn't correct

Comment: you're doing a lot of unnecessary stuff in your code with a lot of functions. Why not read the first input, do the division and then just print the result. This can be done in a loop.

Comment: @TrishulSinghChoudhary these are required (it's an assignment).

Comment: DisplayArray method written by you ?

Comment: Step 0:  Get the code to compile.  `return = value` is a syntax error, so you don't yet actually have a program to debug.  It should be `return value`.  _Then_ figure out why it doesn't do what you expect.  Change one thing at a time.  Understand what each line does on its own.

Comment: @SayantanMandal It was part of a template the professor gave me from another project. I just copied it and updated some of the specifics.

Comment: @IanMcLaird I know, I'm not the best with this. I keep digging myself further into the rabbit hole.  I'm trying to fix that though.

Comment: As a tip to beginners:  You'll make life much easier for yourself when debugging by choosing better variable names.  `arrIn`, `arr1In`, etc. are not very good names.  The name of a variable should describe what the variable is _for_ within its scope.  The names you've chosen in your main method are pretty good.  The ones you're using in the helper methods are not.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your main problem.  Your `mpg` method should look like this. You need to return all
the averages in an array so the return values need to be an array.

And you need to cast one of the `int[]` arrays to double so you don't drop the fractions in the division process.

```
    public static double[] mpg(int[] arrOneIn, int[] arrTwoIn) {

        double[] retValues = new double[arrOneIn.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < arrOneIn.length; i++) {
            retValues[i] = (double) arrOneIn[i] / arrTwoIn[i];
        }
        return retValues;
    }
```